# asp.net sql for "top 10 ordered in ascending order by the items within the top 10"

Tags: asp.net, sqlcommand

I need to use a database using ASP.NET and to take the top 10 items and sort them in ascending order within the top 10.  I have used combinations of the following and have not got them to work:

TOP 10 [rows]
LIMIT (not supported)
ORDER BY [rows] ASC

Comment: For clarification, I want to take the top 10 items and order only the top 10 items (and still not show the other items after the tenth) so I want to take the top 10 first and then sort second.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT TOP(10) FROM <tableName> ORDER BY <columnName> ASC`?  You have to pick a column to order the rows by.

Comment: what do you want the top 10 to be based on, tables are in some order, even if you neglect to specify one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (may not be 100% here, don't have SQL in front of me), but I wouldn't recommend not specifying some kind of order by on the inner select, as if the underlying clustered index changes that would change your results.

```
select *
from 
(select top 10 *
from mytable) as x
order by x.mycolumn asc
```

Comment: Curious - why the subquery?  Is that to ensure the ordering is done on only the 10 rows selected, and not all the rows in the table?

Comment: because he didn't want the 10 items ordered initially, at least that what I got from the badly worded question.

Comment: Nevermind.  I was using the wrong database.  The correct one had only 10 elements.  I am so sorry.  Please close this thread.  I am an idiot.